# How to validate combo box with bootstrap validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, grails

I want to validate my form fields to check if it is empty or not. That's why I am using bootstrap validation. But it's validating only on my text fields not on select box. If I select no value it is submitting the form with null of that select box. I have goggled it but no result I found. Can any one please help me on this please? I am also using grails. Here are my one of text field and one of select box given below :

my textfield >>>

```
 <g:textField name="presidentName" id="presidentName" class="form-control" required=""/>
```

my select box >>>

```
<g:select class="form-control"
      name="divisionId"
      id="divisionId"
      from="${division}"
      optionKey="id"
      optionValue="name"
      noSelection="['null':'Select Division']"
      width="130"
      required="required"
      onchange="loadDistrict(this.value)"/>
```

my validation on document ready >>>

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wardCommittee').bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                divisionId: {
                    message: 'The Division Name is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        required: {
                            message: 'Division is required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                },
                presidentName: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Ward President Name is required and can not be empty'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've attempted to use a validator that doesn't exist. For the field `divisionId`, you are attempting to use a validator called `required`. According to [this documentation](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/), `required` doesn't exist.

Much like you are using with `presidentName`, I'm sure you meant to use the `notEmpty` validator.

`divisionId: {
    message: 'The Division Name is not valid',
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Division is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
}`

I'm not sure if it is just a copy/paste error, but in addition, it looks like you are missing the bracket that closes the `validators` object in your `divisionId` object. I've included it in the above code, however.

Comment: thanks for your approach. It does not work. But I have made this work and is giving it as a answere.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the issue. Just keep the select box default value is empty instead of null at noSelection attribute and it works. Here it as follows >>>

```
<g:select class="form-control"
  name="divisionId"
  id="divisionId"
  from="${division}"
  optionKey="id"
  optionValue="name"
  noSelection="['':'Select Division']"
  width="130"
  required="required"
  onchange="loadDistrict(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you still had to change the validator in your javascript, correct? Unless you wrote it yourself, the "required" validator does not exist in the library.